# Trigonometry? Get the "half" of a triangle from hypotenuse and cathetus

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I've only got the following parts of a triangle:

- Line A to B
- Line B to C

And optionally the Line from A to C if needed?

I'm trying to get the point X

[image: Triangle]

Now the problem is, i've got absolutly no idea of trigonometry so I dont even know how to search for it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might help to give some context to the problem, e.g. is this a math homework problem or is it some practical thing where you need to find point X to make something, etc? Also, please clarify what you mean when you say that you have Line A to B - does this mean you are given (or know) the length of this line? And are you given (or know) the angle between line AB and line BC?

Comment: Specifically, I'm trying to solve a programmatic problem. I'm trying to get the closest point between two interpolated points of a cubic spline to interpolate between them. This might help: http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/741/8fqi.png - I've got O1 (closest point) and O2 (second closest) and try to interpolate to the closest point to CurrentPosition (closest distance) Edit: Y on that image

Comment: OK - So I assume you have the (x, y) coordinates of points $O_1$ and $O_2$? Do you also have the coordinates of the CurrentPosition?

Comment: Exactly. And yes I also got (x, y) of CurrentPosition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, then working off your diagram above and assuming AX is perpendicular to BC, you can proceed as follows:
Let's call the co-ordinates of point A $(x_a, y_a)$, point B $(x_b, y_b)$, point C $(x_c, y_c)$ and point X $(x, y)$.
For line BC we can write: $\frac{y-y_c}{x-x_c}=\frac{y_b-y_c}{x_b-x_c}=m$ where $m$ represents the slope of this line. This leads to:
$y=y_c+mx-mx_c\tag{1}$

Similarly, for line AX we can write: $\frac{y-y_a}{x-x_a}=-\frac{1}{m}$ (since line AX is perpendicular to line BC). This leads to:
$y=y_a-\frac{x}{m}+\frac{x_a}{m}\tag{2}$

Now just equate equations (1) and (2) and solve for $x$ and then use either of these equations to find $y$. $(x, y)$ will then be the point you desire.

You will have to be careful in dealing with vertical lines as their slopes will turn out to be infinite.

To help you along, if you equate (1) and (2) you'll get:
$y_c+mx-mx_c=y_a-\frac{x}{m}+\frac{x_a}{m}$
Then multiply both sides by $m$ to get:
$my_c+m^2x-m^2x_c=my_a-x+x_a$
Take all terms involving $x$ to the left-hand-side of the equals and all others to the right-hand-side to get:
$(m^2+1)x=m(y_a-y_c)+x_a+m^2x_c$
Then divide both sides by $(m^2+1)$ to get:
$\large x=\frac{m(y_a-y_c)+x_a+m^2x_c}{m^2+1}\tag{3}$

This will give you a value for the $x$ co-ordinate of point X which you can then use in equation (1) to calculate the corresponding $y$ value for point X.

Comment: Is point X (x,y) my target point in this case? And is m = (Yb - Yc) / (Xb - Xc) ? What is mx and mxc ? (Thanks so far!)

Comment: @SlapY -- correct X (x,y) is your target point and you have the correct expression for m. $mx=m\times x$ and $mx_c=m\times x_c$

Comment: Oh - of course, sorry.

Comment: np -- happens to the best of us - that's what makes us Human. :)

Comment: ;). I just tried several things but it seems that I'm unable to "equate equations (1) and (2)" due to the fact that my english isn't the best and my math skills are way below that - so I don't quite know what to do. Plus I don't know how to solve for X.

Comment: Okay, I think I slightly understand it now. Thank you very much. I'm going to try to replicate this way a few times to understand it more clearly!

Answer (score 0):

$X=B+\frac{(A-B)\cdot (C-B)}{||C-B||^2} (C-B)$

Comment: Deliciously succinct. But since the OP doesn't know any trigonometry, he probably doesn't know about vectors and norms and dot products, either.